# Reversing bit rotations

Tags: assembly

so I have a question regarding the assembly instructions `ror` and `rol`:
Is it possible to properly reverse them?
So assuming I have something like

```
ROR        EDX, 0x4
```

and know the contents of `EDX` after this instruction, is it mathematically possible to  find out the initial value of `EDX`? If so, can anyone explain to me how it's done?
Sadly I couldn't find any good answer to this so far, so I would be really happy if someone could help me with this :)

Answer (score 3):

For `ror`/`rol` you just use the reverse operation - `rol`/`ror` as bits are rotated - nothing is lost.

`0xdeadbeef rol 5` -> `0xd5b7ddfb`

`0xd5b7ddfb ror 5` -> `0xdeadbeef`